# How to get user information from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt, mern

I've been struggling to grab the information from local Storage. I want to get the
**username**  and **._id** of the current user who logs in and render it to my navbar as well as redirecting to the profile of the current user via Link.

I can grab its information after I refresh once I already logged in

this is my local storage [local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQm6c.png)

When I log it in first, I encounter this problem. This is what shows after logging in
[First Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg7kJ.png)

But once I refresh the page [Refresh Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLF66.png)

sorry if i used too much image, my english is not good and I can't find the exact words

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.user)
  const user2 = JSON.parse(user).username
  const id = JSON.parse(user)._id

return (
    <Typography marginRight={2} sx={{color: {xs: 'white', md: 'black'}}}> Hello  
    {user2}  </Typography>

    <Link to={`/edit_user/${id}`} style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 
         'inherit'}}>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
              {settings[0]}
            </MenuItem>
     </Link>
      )
}
```

userSlice.js

```
 import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const user = localStorage.getItem("token")

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState : {
    user: user ? user : null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ''
  },
  reducers: {getUserStart: (state) =>{
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isError = false;
    },
    getUserSuccess:(state, action) =>{
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    getUserFailure: (state, action) =>{
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.message = action.payload
      state.user = null
    }
  }

})
```

apiCalls.js

```
 export const getUser = async (dispatch,id) =>{
       getUserStart()
       try {
            const getUser = await publicRequest.get('/users/find/'+id)
            dispatch(getUserSuccess(getUser.data))
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(getUserFailure())
        }
    }export const loginUser = async (userData, dispatch) =>{
    dispatch(loginStart())
    try {
        const res = await publicRequest.post('/auth/login', userData)
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data))
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
    } catch (error) {
        const message =
        "Wrong Username or Email "
        dispatch(loginFailure(message))
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show what is `user` value on each render ? clear the localStorage before logging ...

Comment: This is what it looks like before I logged in Before I logged In: [Before I logged in] (ibb.co/7SxJHWD) After I logged In. [After Login in] (https://ibb.co/W6JsQR5)